# Doctrine 2 self-referencing entity won't return the parent id

Tags: doctrine-orm

I've set up a self-referencing entity per the manual here:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html%23one-to-many-self-referencing

My class is Page (instead of Category, like in the docs). In my entity 
class I have a toArray() method that I've implemented that will give 
me back the values of my member variables. For those fields that are 
associations, I've made sure to grab the associated class object then 
grab the id. I'm doing this to populate a form. Here is the code from 
my toArray() method in my Page entity as well as my PageService 
function to grab a Page object and my Page Controller code that calls 
toArray() to populate my form.

http://pastie.org/1686419

As I say in the code comments, when the toArray() method is called in 
the Page Controller, all values get populated except for parent id. 
page_type is also a ManyToOne association and it gets populated no 
problem. Explicitly grabbing the parent id from the Page object 
outside of the toArray() method (in the Page Controller) does return 
the parent id value. (See code.)

As a side note, I'm using __get() and __set() in my Page entity instead of full blown getters/setters.

Comment: I just found that if I do implement a getId() getter directly and use that in my toArray() method that it will return the id value. Why, is the question. Why does it work getting the values directly (without a full getter) outside of the toArray() method (in my controller)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are getting caught out by proxies. When you have an association in Doctrine 2, the related objects are not returned directly as objects, but as subclasses which do not fill their properties until a method is called (because of lazy loading to save database queries).

Since you are calling the property directly (with $this->parent->id) without invoking any method the object properties are all empty.

This page http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html#a-first-prototype has a warning about this type of thing in the warning box. Although yours isn't a public property, you are accessing as though it were because that object is of the same class and the same problem is occuring.

Comment: I'm using the __get() and __set() methods which allow you to access object properties as if they were public. I used the same method to retrieve the id from another association (page_type) of the same class and it worked fine. The problem is directly tied to this particular association and I feel it must have something to do with the fact that it is a reference back to the same type of entity. Also, as I mentioned above, I can make the direct call to the parent id outside of my toArray() method and it works. It's only within the toArray() method that it won't retrieve the value.

Comment: __get and __set only work on inaccessible properties. Because it's of the same class, they are accessible and so it's just directly accessing the private properties. But because no functions have been called, the proxy hasn't been loaded yet and so all the values are empty.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are saying now. However, the problem only occurs with this one value even within my toArray() method. I can access the page_type id within my toArray() method directly with no problems. 'page_type' => $this->page_type->id As far as I can tell I've not got any other code that precedes my toArray() call which would load the proxy with the value for page_type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of exactly what is causing your described behavior, but you're probably better anyway to have your toArray() method call getters/setters rather than having toArray() operate directly on the class properties.  This will give you consistency so that if you implement custom getters for certain properties, you'll always get back the same result from toArray() and the getter.

A rough example:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class MyEntity {

    // ....

    /** @Column */
    protected $foo;


    public function setFoo($val)
    {
        $this->foo = $val;
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return 'hello ' . $this->foo;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $fields = array('foo');
        $values = array();
        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $method = 'get' . ucfirst($field);
            if (is_callable(array($this, $method)) {
                $fields[$field] = $this->$method();
            } else {
                $fields[$field] = $this->$field;
            }
        }
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Now you get the same result:

```
<?php
$e = new MyEntity;
$e->setFoo('world');
$e->getFoo(); // returns 'hello world'
$e->toArray(); // returns array('foo' => 'hello world')
```